# wso2api manager 4.0 with Post Request Error: Not Found

Tags: rest, .net-core, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I  want  to  secure  .net  core  api  with  wso2 api  manager ,for  that  i  have  enabled  swagger on  the  api  and   able  to  get  post  response .  I have  created  Api  with swagger defination

```
http://localhost:5000/swagger/v1/swagger.json
```

and  given  endpoint http://localhost:5000/api/BigData which  will get  response in  swagger  ui

now  i  am  trying  to  test  with  api  working  with  token for  that  wso2api  showing  error

curl request   from  wso2-am

````
curl  reuqest  semding  from  wso2-am  ```curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8280/api/v1/api/BigData' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Internal-Key: eyJraWQiOiJnYXRld2F5X2NlcnRpZmljYXRlX2FsaWFzIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbkBjYXJib24uc3VwZXIiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvbG9jYWxob3N0Ojk0NDNcL29hdXRoMlwvdG9rZW4iLCJrZXl0eXBlIjoiUFJPRFVDVElPTiIsInN1YnNjcmliZWRBUElzIjpbeyJzdWJzY3JpYmVyVGVuYW50RG9tYWluIjpudWxsLCJuYW1lIjoiQmlnRGF0YUFQSSIsImNvbnRleHQiOiJcL2FwaVwvdjEiLCJwdWJsaXNoZXIiOiJhZG1pbiIsInZlcnNpb24iOiJ2MSIsInN1YnNjcmlwdGlvblRpZXIiOm51bGx9XSwiZXhwIjoxNjI0OTIyMzg3LCJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiSW50ZXJuYWxLZXkiLCJpYXQiOjE2MjQ4NjIzODcsImp0aSI6ImZiYjQ2OGQ0LWUyOTItNGEyZC1hZmEzLTdhNzFlODUxNTlhNCJ9.Xkz9jigCPs3I65kI40rigE6L8mA-w4kks3n7Cabahg1dMVEo8AVs64PXuKBshucuT_vk5ms-7wFiIiI0pdXrL1ymOlEacBtW2r1F-WvV7o9SVw6lpF4EQNsIFi96Exe5Gg0k2wSaG1iErJ2P8boOQGI66fudGfjC-Gt1RJxfE-ZwQ_aS7fNur4G7HFAbBOdSq3yNDWjsMiv9k4IBlQ-IkJj88zSM6eXnHbtiAJKB84bAkFX7PDxXzjdItGkTKBx2oW11SO27xvqlrlJCHh6dcvEKb1_XZIjyrrvQjTGTX0cTgUlL0HQFOL9RwavrDwXh_fsP51zhGbbLozuUbhUKWg' \
  -d '{
  "messageID": "string",
  "tenantName": "string",
  "tenantID": "string",
  "entityID": "string",
  "entityType": "string",
  "dataType": "string",
  "messageKind": "string",
  "routing": "string",
  "payload": "string",
  "type": "string",
  "clientID": "string",
  "userID": "string",
  "isAdmin": true,
  "fabric": "string",
  "capabilityId": "string",
  "sourceSystem": "string",
  "applicationName": "string"
}'```
````

[image]
when  i  check  the  endpoint  again  its showing  method  not  allowed
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try invoking the API using the cURL command and share the output? The `405` Method Not allowed is produced due to your trying to invoke the GET resource from the browser (if you are executing a URL from the Browser, it will be GET and POST). Also, can you specify the Production Endpoint that has been configured in the API Manager? If you have mentioned the complete URL of the actual endpoint as Production Endpoint, then the API needs a refactoring

Comment: here  is  the  curl  request  which  i  am  sending  with  swagger post  client ```curl -X 'POST' \  'http://localhost:5000/api/BigData' \  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \  -d '{  "tenantName": "string",  "tenantID": "string",  "entityID": "string",  "entityType": "string",  "dataType": "string",  "messageKind": "string",  "routing": "string",  "payload": "string",  "type": "string",  "clientID": "string",  "userID": "string",  "isAdmin": true,  "fabric": "string",  "capabilityId": "string",  "sourceSystem": "string",  "applicationName": "string"}' ```

Comment: api  endpoint  URL  i  have  set  ```http://localhost:5000/api/BigData```  for   both  sandbox  and  Production

Comment: i  have  edited  post  for response  screens

Comment: Thank you for the update. I believe that you have created an API Resource with `POST` as `/api/BigData` in the API Manager. If yes, update the `Production` and `Sandbox` endpoint as `http://localhost:5000` (without specifying the complete URL, because the API Manager will append the Resource at the end of the mentioned endpoint). Save the API and try out the scenario

Comment: genius !yes  worked  after  having  correct  Endpoint  url ,but  this  things  i  did  not  find  anywhere  in  doc  ,thanks  a  lot  for your  help

Comment: Great!! ... I'll add an answer explaining the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with the shared information, I believe that you have configured an API resource as `/api/BigData`. If that is the case, update the `Production` and `Sandbox` endpoints as `http://localhost:5000` and not with the complete URL of the actual endpoint to overcome the `404` errors.

The API Manager uses and appends the API Resources that are defined at the end of the Production/Sandbox endpoints. So, when you are configuring an API and exposing that, you have to be sure of choosing the correct endpoints.

For example:

If you have an actual Backend server with the following endpoint `https://backendserver/api/v1/get` and `https://backendserver/api/v1/post` then you have to configure an API in the API Manager as following

- Create an API with the following two resources

  - `/get`
  - `/post`
- Configure the Production / Sandbox endpoints as `https://backendserver/api/v1`

Then, if you invoke the API with the API Manager endpoint (`https://apimanager:8243/your-api/v1/get`), the `/get` resource will get appended to the configured endpoint and the request will be served as `https://backendserver/api/v1/get`.

Hope this explains and gives you a brief understanding of the URL mappings in API Manager.